# How to fuse all .js files in one single .js in the final build?

Tags: maven, dojo

I need to compact every .js files I have inside of my /src folder in one big .js file containing all of them one after another. 
This big file should be put inside of the maven's /target folder in place of single .js files.

Is this possible with a maven or dojo plugin?
Thanks

Comment: Take a look here: https://github.com/samaxes/minify-maven-plugin

Comment: Mmm...this one seems to just minimize the .js files, but still doesn't fuse them in one single file.

Comment: It does: "Minify Maven Plugin **combines and minimizes** your CSS and JavaScript files for faster page loading"

Comment: I don't know what complexity maven adds to the equation, but have you at least read about [Dojo's build tool](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.10/build/)?